# Книга по оптимизации запросов oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Какие есть книги по оптимизации sql запросов oracle на русском языке? Нужны именно запросы, pl/sql на втором плане.  Желательно, чтобы книгу можно было читать человеку со средними знаниями написания запросов oracle  без навыков администрирования.

Comment: напоминание желавшим ответить: литературу можно перечислить в описании метки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info

Answer (score 1):

В свое время читал "Oracle. Основы стоимостной оптимизации Дж. Льюис". Показалось годным материалом.